# Keep track of 3rd party app use

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I have specifications from my employer. He wants me to track the use of 3rd party apps from inside of our application. Our application is suppose to act as an operating system. We launch 3rd party apps from our application. Is there any way to track how long a user is using these apps?

The only thing I could think of is starting the timer when I start the intent to launch the app, and upon return to our application stopping the timer. Any ideas on a more concrete idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [Interacting with Other Applications](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) does any of that apply? Your method does seem like the only possible way but I would do it by checking the system time in the onPause and onResume J.I.C your stops whilst being on the other app :) Hope I helped!

Comment: I will look into this. And great suggestion. +1 for response and answer. Cheers!